# jQuery each function IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some links in a page that i'd like to change from

```
<span id="lireArticle">
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/4_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>

<span id="lireArticle">
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/2_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>

<span id="lireArticle">
<a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/3_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>
```

to

```
  <span id="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
    </span>

    <span id="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
    </span>

    <span id="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
    </span>
```

This works in Firefox, IE9, IE8 but not **IE7**!

it just changes the first link in IE7

```
jQuery("#lireArticle a").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
})
```

How can i get it to work in IE7?

Comment: please describe what it is supposed to do, and what actually happens.

Comment: I added more details in the questions

Comment: in IE7 it changes only the first link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Use `class=""` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using the same ID multiple times on the page. The ID of the element should be unique. Your code is finding the first instance of an element with the ID of "lireArticle" and changing all its `a`'s. I suggest using `class=""` instead.

**Markup:**

```
<span class="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/4_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>

<span class="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/2_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>

<span class="lireArticle">
    <a href="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel/3_.000/DispForm.aspx?ID=4" class="action">Lire l'article</a>
</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(".lireArticle a").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/'));
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Oops made syntax error on previous post, updated.  If you don't want to change the links by adding a class just use a different selector.

```
$('a[href^="/Lists/ListeActualitesCarrousel"]').each(function(){
     var newURL = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\/(\d)_.(\d{3})\//,'/');
     $(this).href(newURL);
});
```